# How to connect Plug.Router with Plug function

Tags: elixir, plug

I'm trying to set up a very simple, basic HTTP API in Elixir. I thought using Phoenix for such a thing is totally overkill, so wanted to do it simply by using Plug. And I can do it by setting up a basic Router like this:

```
defmodule Example.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug Plug.Logger
  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/" do    
    data = do_something_with_conn(conn)

    send_resp(conn, 200, Poison.encode!(data))
  end

  match _, do: send_resp(conn, 404, "Not Found")
end
```

However, I can't figure out how to connect this router to another Plug function. Say, somewhere I have this plug-compliant function:

```
defmodule RandomPlug do
  import Plug.Conn
  def random_plug(conn, opts) do
    whatever(conn)
  end
end
```

How do I connect it to the Router? I've tried using this syntax from the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html#forward/2):

```
forward "/", to: RandomPlug.random_plug
```

And other variations, but I can't get it to compile and/or work. For example the version above complains about there being no random_plug/0 function.

Yes, I can get it to work with a whole Plug module (with `init` and `call`), but I want to figure out how to get it working with a function. Perhaps it will give me a better understanding of some Elixir specifics, and it should be possible according to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the source of `Plug.Builder` and did not find a way to specify a module and function name combination in `plug`. It [seems to be limited to either a function name or a module name](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/e9f71081f97d85daec5e8b1cea57f7c5c7a54d4d/lib/plug/builder.ex#L244-L250) (in which case it'll call `module.init/2`). But, you *can* `import` the functions from the module and then treat the imported functions as local functions:

```
defmodule Example.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  ...

  import RandomPlug
  plug :random_plug
end
```